# Manipulating an Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

What is the correct way of square rooting both sides of the inequality $$\text{Im}(z)^2 < 3\text{Re}(z)^2\;\text{?}$$

Comment: Both sides of the inequality are real numbers, so you handle them "as usual".

Answer (score 5):

$$
|\text{Im}\,(z)| < \sqrt3\,|\text{Re}\,(z)|.
$$

Comment: Are the modulus signs needed on the LHS as $\text{Im}(z) \in \mathbb{R}$? I'm assuming you meant a strictly less than sign?

Comment: @Sam The modulus here is the usual absolute value for real numbers.

Comment: @Sam: as I always tell my students, the square root of $(-3)^2$ is not $-3$. So $1^2<(-2)^2$ doesn't allow you to claim that $1<-2$. As for the "less than" sign, yes, that was a typo and Austin has already corrected it.

Comment: Can that square root of 3 give a plus and a minus sign or just a positive square root? Is the RHS $|\pm \sqrt{3} \text{Re}(z)| = \sqrt{3}|\text{Re}(z)|$?

Comment: The common practice is that when you write the square root of a positive real number, you mean the positive square root. Because of that, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score 3):

As in any other such case:

$$\forall\,x,a\in\Bbb R\,\,,\,a>0\;\;\;,\;x^2<a\Longrightarrow |x|<\sqrt a\Longleftrightarrow -\sqrt a< x<\sqrt a$$

So here

$$Im(z)^2<3\,Re(z)^2\Longrightarrow |Im(z)|<\sqrt 3\,|Re(z)|$$